# Selenium Webdriver - Java; Find and click a button (with eventlistener) in a table

Tags: java, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

First question on stack for me. After a day of research, no progress on my end.

Trying out WebDriver in Netbeans for testing of our services, using WebDriver because we want to test fileuploads at a later stage.

**page 1 (works)**

```
// path of FireFox Driver
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Users\\stevenglasius\\Documents\\WebDriver\\geckodriver.exe");
    WebDriver driverFireFox = new FirefoxDriver();

    // website url
    driverFireFox.get("https://website.nl");
    Thread.sleep(3000);

    // login
    WebElement userName = driverFireFox.findElement(By.id("login:j_idt33"));
    userName.sendKeys("willCost@me.my");
    WebElement passWord = driverFireFox.findElement(By.id("login:j_idt38"));
    passWord.sendKeys("jobIfITellYa");
    WebElement GoToApp = driverFireFox.findElement(By.id("login:j_idt42_label"));
    GoToApp.click();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    WebElement GoToProductManager = driverFireFox.findElement(By.id("login:j_idt42_7"));
    GoToProductManager.click();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    WebElement login = driverFireFox.findElement(By.id("login:j_idt47"));
    login.click();
    Thread.sleep(5000);
```

**Next page/webapplication is loaded.**
I need to click a button with id: "menuForm:j_idt823"

tried by id:

```
WebElement upload = driverFireFox.findElement(By.id("menuForm:j_idt823"));
upload.click();
```

tried by xpath:

```
WebElement productUpload = driverFireFox.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='menuForm:j_idt823']/table/tbody/tr[4]"));
productUpload.click();
```

tried with expected conditions:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driverFireFox, 10);
...
WebElement productUpload = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("menuForm:j_idt823")));
productUpload.click();
```

**Same error: Unable to locate element..**
What might be an issue, there is an event?
`Thread.sleep(5000);` before the findelement for loading the page was included.
I am kinda new at programming, please help me!

HTML[event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6oyg.png)

complete table:

```
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td>
        <span style="font-weight: bold">Start Scherm</span>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <button id="menuForm:j_idt821" name="menuForm:j_idt821" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-icon-left button" onclick="PrimeFaces.ab({s:&quot;menuForm:j_idt821&quot;,u:&quot;menuForm tabView&quot;});return false;" style="margin-left:10px !important;margin-bottom:5px !important;margin-top:10px !important;" type="submit" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
            <span class="ui-button-icon-left ui-icon ui-c fa fa-home"/>
            <span class="ui-button-text ui-c">Home</span>
        </button>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <span style="font-weight: bold">Update &amp; Process Uw Data</span>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <button id="menuForm:j_idt823" name="menuForm:j_idt823" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-icon-left button" onclick="PrimeFaces.ab({s:&quot;menuForm:j_idt823&quot;,u:&quot;menuForm tabView&quot;});return false;" style="margin-left:10px !important;margin-bottom:5px !important;margin-top:10px !important;" type="submit" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
            <span class="ui-button-icon-left ui-icon ui-c fa fa-upload"/>
            <span class="ui-button-text ui-c">Product Upload</span>
        </button>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <button id="menuForm:j_idt824" name="menuForm:j_idt824" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-icon-left button" onclick="PrimeFaces.ab({s:&quot;menuForm:j_idt824&quot;,u:&quot;menuForm tabView&quot;});return false;" style="margin-left:10px !important;margin-bottom:5px !important;" type="submit" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
            <span class="ui-button-icon-left ui-icon ui-c fa fa-arrows-alt"/>
            <span class="ui-button-text ui-c">Product Data Management</span>
        </button>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <button id="menuForm:j_idt825" name="menuForm:j_idt825" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-icon-left ui-state-disabled button" onclick="PrimeFaces.ab({s:&quot;menuForm:j_idt825&quot;,u:&quot;menuForm tabView&quot;});return false;" style="margin-left:10px !important;margin-bottom:5px !important;" type="submit" disabled="disabled" role="button" aria-disabled="true">
            <span class="ui-button-icon-left ui-icon ui-c fa fa-upload"/>
            <span class="ui-button-text ui-c">Voorraad Upload</span>
        </button>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <button id="menuForm:j_idt826" name="menuForm:j_idt826" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-icon-left button" onclick="PrimeFaces.ab({s:&quot;menuForm:j_idt826&quot;,u:&quot;menuForm tabView&quot;});return false;" style="margin-left:10px !important;margin-bottom:10px !important;" type="submit" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
            <span class="ui-button-icon-left ui-icon ui-c fa fa-upload"/>
            <span class="ui-button-text ui-c">Prijs Upload</span>
        </button>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <fieldset id="menuForm:j_idt827" class="ui-fieldset ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-hidden-container ui-fieldset-toggleable ui-hidden-container" style="border: none !important;padding: 0em 0em !important;margin-left: 10px !important;max-width:130px !important;width:130px !important;" data-widget="widget_menuForm_j_idt827">
            <legend class="ui-fieldset-legend ui-corner-all ui-state-default">
                <span class="ui-fieldset-toggler ui-icon ui-icon-plusthick"/>Create &amp; Maintain Uw Eigen Templates</legend>
            <div class="ui-fieldset-content" style="display:none">
                <button id="menuForm:j_idt828" name="menuForm:j_idt828" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-icon-left button" onclick="PrimeFaces.ab({s:&quot;menuForm:j_idt828&quot;,u:&quot;menuForm tabView&quot;});return false;" style="margin-bottom:5px !important;margin-top:10px !important;" type="submit" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
                    <span class="ui-button-icon-left ui-icon ui-c fa fa-keyboard-o"/>
                    <span class="ui-button-text ui-c">Product File</span>
                </button>
                <button id="menuForm:j_idt829" name="menuForm:j_idt829" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-icon-left button" onclick="PrimeFaces.ab({s:&quot;menuForm:j_idt829&quot;,u:&quot;menuForm tabView&quot;});return false;" style="margin-bottom:5px !important;" type="submit" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
                    <span class="ui-button-icon-left ui-icon ui-c fa fa-keyboard-o"/>
                    <span class="ui-button-text ui-c">Voorraad File</span>
                </button>
                <button id="menuForm:j_idt830" name="menuForm:j_idt830" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-icon-left button" onclick="PrimeFaces.ab({s:&quot;menuForm:j_idt830&quot;,u:&quot;menuForm tabView&quot;});return false;" style="margin-bottom:10px !important;" type="submit" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
                    <span class="ui-button-icon-left ui-icon ui-c fa fa-keyboard-o"/>
                    <span class="ui-button-text ui-c">Prijs File</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <input id="menuForm:j_idt827_collapsed" name="menuForm:j_idt827_collapsed" value="true" type="hidden">
            </fieldset>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <fieldset id="menuForm:j_idt831" class="ui-fieldset ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-hidden-container ui-fieldset-toggleable ui-hidden-container" style="border: none !important;padding: 0em 0em !important;margin-left: 10px !important;max-width:130px !important;width:130px !important;margin-top: 10px !important;" data-widget="widget_menuForm_j_idt831">
                <legend class="ui-fieldset-legend ui-corner-all ui-state-default">
                    <span class="ui-fieldset-toggler ui-icon ui-icon-plusthick"/>Downloads</legend>
                <div class="ui-fieldset-content" style="display:none">
                    <button id="menuForm:j_idt832" name="menuForm:j_idt832" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-icon-left button" onclick="PrimeFaces.monitorDownload(start, stop);;" style="margin-bottom:5px !important;margin-top:10px !important;" type="submit" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
                        <span class="ui-button-icon-left ui-icon ui-c fa fa-download"/>
                        <span class="ui-button-text ui-c">Download Seller Report</span>
                    </button>
                    <button id="menuForm:j_idt833" name="menuForm:j_idt833" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-icon-left button" onclick="PrimeFaces.ab({s:&quot;menuForm:j_idt833&quot;,u:&quot;menuForm tabView&quot;});return false;" style="margin-bottom:10px !important;" type="submit" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
                        <span class="ui-button-icon-left ui-icon ui-c fa fa-download"/>
                        <span class="ui-button-text ui-c">Download Onetrail Templates</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <input id="menuForm:j_idt831_collapsed" name="menuForm:j_idt831_collapsed" value="true" type="hidden">
                </fieldset>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <button id="menuForm:j_idt834" name="menuForm:j_idt834" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-icon-left button" onclick="PrimeFaces.ab({s:&quot;menuForm:j_idt834&quot;,u:&quot;menuForm tabView&quot;});return false;" style="margin-left:10px !important;margin-top:10px !important;" type="submit" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
                    <span class="ui-button-icon-left ui-icon ui-c fa fa-user"/>
                    <span class="ui-button-text ui-c">User profile</span>
                </button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Comment: is the table inside any iframe?

Comment: Yes the table is inside an iframe

Comment: So are you switching to the frame before you perform action on the table? (like with `driver.switchTo().frame()` ?

Comment: <iframe id="iframe6" src="https://acc-apps.onetrail.net/productmanager/" class="ui-widget-content iframeStyle"></iframe>

something like this?
riverFireFox.switchTo().frame("iframe6");

Comment: It worked! thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This should do it.

```
WebElement upload = driverFireFox.findElement(By.xpath("//button[text()='Product Upload']"))
upload.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Shivam Mishra answered my queston.

The solution was in an iframe:
solved with:

```
driverFireFox.switchTo().frame("iframe6");
```

Many thanks Shivam!

Comment: never posted before because I tought it would take ages. My first real experience with Stack Overflow :D